# Landscapes and Symbols

Tags: pattern, visual

### Fill in the Blank... With an Image

An innovative type of puzzle. What should be filled in place of the question mark?

> [image]

Comment: the only thing i can come up with is rot13(n cvpgher bs n dhrfgvba znex) but I suspect I'm mistaken.  Very clever puzzle at any rate.

Comment: When you say "in place of the question mark" you mean the black one in the middle, right? Not the white one to the right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SteveV identified most of the images. The top row is the most important:

> cwm, fjord, bank...

This sequence is

> a (semi-)well-known perfect pangram: "Cwm fjord bank glyphs vext quiz". So the missing image is something to represent "vext", such as the following
>
>  [image]

Comment: wow. i never thought to google rot13(pjz swbeq onax).  They looked so unrelated to me! sooo close.

Comment: What! You are clever. I also identified the images. Had no idea how close I was.

Comment: Or honestly, you could just leave the question mark there - it already basically fits the meaning of that word...

Answer (score 4):

i'll take a (admittedly weak) shot at it.

First

> doing reverse image searches of the five pictures gives the following

One

> is a cwm in Wales

Two

> is a Norwegian Fjord

Three

> is a generic river bank

On the second row, one

> are pictish rune symbols

Three

> is a quiz vector symbol (stock picture)

So

> I could make nothing of the first row (cwm fjord bank or cwm fjord river didn't seem to lead to anything for me).  But the second row is Pict ?? Quiz.  So i looked for an image of Ur to make "Picture Quiz", and came up with

This image

> [image]

Which is

> a picture of the ruins of the ancient city of Ur

And that is my guess.